# Json request failing because of backslashes in request body?

Tags: c#, json, serialization, restsharp

I currently started on the development of porting an existing app to a Windows store app.

I'm using `Restsharp.portable` (by FubarDevelopment) and `JSON.Net` for the serialization.

I have tried to perform a login to by building the request object and adding the serialized object as the requestBody.
However, this request allways fails with `HttpStatusCode 500`. When I take a look in Fiddler I can see that the JSON body still contains the escape slashes.
When I edit the request manually from Fiddler, remove those backslashes and execute it, the request get's processed with a `HttpStatusCode 200`.

Does anybody know why it is sending my requestbody with the escape slashes?

This is the raw content as shown in Fiddler

> ```
> POST http://myhost/webmediation/service.php HTTP/1.1
> Accept: application/json, text/json, text/x-json, text/javascript,application/xml, text/xml
> Content-Length: 102
> Accept-Encoding: identity
> Cache-Control: no-cache
> Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
> User-Agent: NativeHost
> Host: 185.7.39.125
> Connection: Keep-Alive
> Pragma: no-cache
> ```

```
"{\"params\":\"p_strLogin\":\"flow@mcs\"},\"jsonrpc\":\"2.0\",\"method\":\"initLogin\",\"id\":\"1\"}"
```

This is the code where I serialize my object and add it to the request

```
var requestJSON = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jsonRequestObject, Formatting.Indented, new JsonSerializerSettings { NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore });

        var request = new RestRequest(resource, method);
        request.AddParameter("application/json; charset=utf-8", requestJSON, ParameterType.RequestBody);
```

SOLVED:
As stated by Pranav Patel, the object was getting serialized a second time. The Restsharp.portable implementation does the JSON serialization when you add the object to the request. Since I was adding an already serialized object to the request, it was getting escaped.

Thank you Pranav!

Comment: how are you performing the serialization?

Comment: show us some code f you tried.

Comment: Pls. show the code where you create, fill and send the request.Did you also have to remove the leading and trailing quote-signs to make it work?

Comment: btw: this part of your JSON is not valid `{\"params\":\"p_strLogin\":\"flow@mcs\"}`